# Xamarin forms Custom Cell diplays only first row

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, custom-cell

I am newbie to Xamarin forms and I would like to create app useful for drivers. I am trying to create custom cell with multiple stacklayouts inside. But in listview there is only first row of my custom cell displayed. Here is my Custom cell code:

```
<ListView x:Name="ListViewRides">
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <ViewCell>
      <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Margin="15">
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
          <Label x:Name="LabelLocationFrom" Text="{Binding PlaceFrom}" Margin="0, 0, 5,0"/>
          <Label Text="->"/>
          <Label x:Name="LabelLocationTo" Text="{Binding PlaceTo}" Margin="5, 0, 0, 0"/>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
          <Label x:Name="LabelTimeFrom" Text="{Binding TimeFrom}" Margin="0, 0, 5,0"/>
          <Label Text="->"/>
          <Label x:Name="LabelTimeTo" Text="{Binding TimeTo}" Margin="5, 0, 0, 0"/>
        </StackLayout>
        <Label x:Name="LabelCustomer" Text="{Binding Customer}"></Label>
      </StackLayout>
    </ViewCell>
  </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Here is the result in displayed in Simulator
[image: Result in simulator]

I do not understand where I am making the mistake, Could someone please help me? For complete overview I am also adding the ViewModel Code:

```
public class RidesViewModel:Bindable
{
    public string PlaceFrom { get; set; }
    public string PlaceTo { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeFrom { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeTo { get; set; }
    public string Load { get; set; }
    public int Weight { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }
    public string ContactPersonFrom { get; set; }
    public string ContactPersonTo { get; set; }
    public string Customer { get; set; }
    public string Trailer { get; set; }
    public bool IsReadyToShow { get; set; }
    public string RideState { get; set; }
}
```

Thank you for advices. I suppose that it is something obvious which I can't see right now.

Comment: It is probably out of view. Try setting the `RowHeight` on your `ListView` to a bigger number and see if something is there.

Comment: You are right, is there any pattern to determine rowsheight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You not being able to see it is probably due to the fact that it is out of view, but it is there.

Set the `RowHeight` property of your `ListView` to a higher value to verify this.

The `RowHeight` should be able to calculate when you set to -1 and set `HasUnevenRows` to true if I'm not mistaken. However that does not always work in my experience. To do make it work you will probably have to go about it with some custom renderers.

Answer (score 1):

You must set your ListView (... or any view) to `HasUnevenRows = True` AND set the **VerticalOptions** to either "CenterAndExpand" or "FillAndExpand" or something else that suits.

Answer (score 0):

After a so much Research i created below Listview with Test data.

just copy and paste the code and check the result.

```
    <ListView HasUnevenRows="true"
              RowHeight="200">
        <ListView.ItemsSource>
            <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                <x:String>Item One</x:String>
                <x:String>Item Two</x:String>
                <x:String>Item Three</x:String>
                <x:String>Item Four</x:String>
                <x:String>Item Five</x:String>
            </x:Array>
        </ListView.ItemsSource>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Frame BorderColor="Red" Padding="0">
                        <Grid Margin="10">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="90" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="90"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <BoxView Grid.Row="0"
                                     Grid.Column="0"
                                     Color="Yellow" />
                            <BoxView Grid.Row="0"
                                     Grid.Column="1"
                                     Color="Black" />
                            <BoxView Grid.Row="1"
                                     Grid.Column="0"
                                     Color="Green" />
                            <BoxView Grid.Row="1"
                                     Grid.Column="1"
                                     Color="Blue" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding}"
                                   FontAttributes="Bold"
                                   TextColor="Red"
                                   HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Frame>
            </ViewCell>
          </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```